# How to run multi tenant application

Tags: quarkus

I am new with quarkus
I tried to check this example https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/hibernate-orm-multi-tenancy-quickstart the SCHEMA Multitenancy . first I run the docker with

```
docker run -it --rm=true --name quarkus_test -e POSTGRES_USER=quarkus_test -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=quarkus_test -e POSTGRES_DB=quarkus_test -p 5432:5432 postgres:13.3
```

and after i run the ./mvnw quarkus:dev I didn't see any schemas of base,mycompany i tried to change the application.properties

```
# General settings
quarkus.log.level=INFO
%test.quarkus.log.level=INFO
%dev.quarkus.log.level=INFO
quarkus.native.native-image-xmx=5G

# Hibernate ORM settings
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=none
quarkus.hibernate-orm.multitenant=SCHEMA
%database.quarkus.hibernate-orm.multitenant=DATABASE

# SCHEMA Tenant Configuration (environment variable expansion is used to facilitate docker-compose setup)
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=quarkus_test
quarkus.datasource.password=quarkus_test
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST_TENANT_BASE:localhost}:${DB_PORT_TENANT_BASE:5432}/quarkus_test
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=8
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size=2
quarkus.flyway.schemas=base,mycompany
quarkus.flyway.locations=schema
quarkus.flyway.migrate-at-start=true
database.quarkus.flyway.schemas=
database.quarkus.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
database.quarkus.flyway.migrate-at-start=true
```

but I didn't see that any scheme was created.
and this file https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/main/hibernate-orm-multi-tenancy-quickstart/src/main/resources/schema/V1.0.0__create_fruits.sql didn't invoke

```
CREATE SEQUENCE base.known_fruits_id_seq;
SELECT setval('base."known_fruits_id_seq"', 3);
CREATE TABLE base.known_fruits
(
  id   INT,
  name VARCHAR(40)
);
INSERT INTO base.known_fruits(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Cherry');
INSERT INTO base.known_fruits(id, name) VALUES (2, 'Apple');
INSERT INTO base.known_fruits(id, name) VALUES (3, 'Banana');

CREATE SEQUENCE mycompany.known_fruits_id_seq;
SELECT setval('mycompany."known_fruits_id_seq"', 3);
CREATE TABLE mycompany.known_fruits
(
  id   INT,
  name VARCHAR(40)
);
INSERT INTO mycompany.known_fruits(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Avocado');
INSERT INTO mycompany.known_fruits(id, name) VALUES (2, 'Apricots');
INSERT INTO mycompany.known_fruits(id, name) VALUES (3, 'Blackberries');
```

Can you please advise ?

Comment: I fallowed the example and I can see mycompany and default schemas and page lists some fruits, so how did you check the database ? personally I just check http://localhost:8080/index.html and see the data there. I had issues with docker, I suggest to remove all and start postgresql from clean.